# MVC5, OWIN, and Ninject - GetOwinContext Issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ninject

I have an MVC5 project that is doing OwinStartup, and I'm using Ninject.MVC5, Ninject.Web.Common.OwinHost, etc.

I have NinjectWebCommon bootstrapping DI and things were working just fine.  Until I started playing with the identity code.

I need to issue a password reset token, which requires a DataProtectionProvider.  No problem, the ApplicationUserManager wires that up in the Create method, which is bound to the OwinContext during startup in Startup.Auth.cs:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    ...
}
```

In my NinjectWebCommon I have the following registrations:

```
kernel.Bind<IDataContext>()
    .ToMethod(ctx => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>())
    .InRequestScope();

kernel.Bind<IApplicationUserManager>()
    .ToMethod(ctx => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>())
    .InRequestScope();
```

The problem I'm having is that the token isn't being issued.  Why isn't that what my question is about?  Well, if I get an instance of the ApplicationUserManager using the Create myself and use that, things work flawlessly.

Next on my plate a reported user creation bug.  Hyphens aren't working in usernames.  In that same ApplicationUserManager.Create method, is the UserValidator code that's overriding the default AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames value.

Again, if I use a self created dependency, it works as expected.  This seems to indicate Ninject's injected dependency isn't using the ApplicationUserManager.Create'd version.

I'm guessing this has to do with the call to: HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext??

Is there something I need to do in order to inject something that relies on the owin context or something else I need to do while registering my resolver?

I've seen other questions here showing UseNinjectMiddleware and UseNinjectWebApi.  I tried that approach, but didn't have any luck, nothing was being injected in...

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!